# I18n for database tables in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How do I create translations to my database table rows?

I recall that you in PHP Symfony could have one table with english rows, another with swedish rows. And in your controller you just specify the language you would like to use and your model would use the appropriate table.

Is this possible in Rails?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should look at globalize gem

https://github.com/svenfuchs/globalize3